# Data is not inserted in database table from windows form

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I am working on a Desktop application. I developed a form in which user enters data. When he clicks the submit button the data is saved in a database name PakReaEstat. The problem  is the data is not inserted in the table and I get an error: `SqlException was Unhandled`.

When I click the Submit button it prompts error.
The code behind the button is as following:

```
protected void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ali-pc/sqlexpress.PakEstateAgency.dbo"); 
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ClientINFO(Application#,LDAReg#,Size,Name,SDW/O,CNIC,Address,Image,giventime)" + 
                                    "values (" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + ",'" + 
                                    textBox2.Text + "','" + 
                                    textBox4.Text + "'," + 
                                    textBox5.Text + "," + 
                                    textBox6.Text + "," + 
                                    textBox7.Text + "," + 
                                    textBox8.Text + 
                                    "," + textBox3.Text + ")", con); 
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    MessageBox.Show("Insertion successfully done");
}
```

Comment: Missing single quotes on last 5 textboxes

Comment: Are you sure you're accessing the database correctly?

Comment: The Folllowng error is occured before insert statment                                                                   "A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Could not open a connection to SQL Server)

Comment: That is not a valid connection string. Maybe valid syntactically, but nobody names their instances after databases and schemas.

Comment: can u please tell me which connection string i have to use?

Answer (score 1):

Check you connection string and the SQL insert statement.

I recommend that you use sql parameters instead of the the textbox text property as value directly.
Beacause this is a common vulnerability, called SQL injection.
I also recommend to use using statement to ensure the connection is closed.

```
using (var con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ali-pc/sqlexpress.PakEstateAgency.dbo"))
            {
                con.Open();
                using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ClientINFO(Application#,LDAReg#,Size,Name,SDW/O,CNIC,Address,Image,giventime)" + "values (@Application#,@LDAReg#, ... )", con))
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Application#", Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text));
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LDAReg#", textBox2.Text);
                    // add the other parameters ...

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Insertion successfully done");
```

Comment: I Have done as u said but problem is same.....my connection with database does not establishing....i am really not know about it please tell me how can i establish connection with sql server.

Comment: the problem is, I cannot assert that your connection string is correct. Maybe the server instance is not correct. Look at the MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/d7469at0(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Always put your code in `try... catch` block if you are doing transaction with datatbase

If your connetion to databse is established and no issue there then

You are missing single quotes on last five textboxes. I suppose that last five columns are of type `nvarchar` in ur datatbse

change command to

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into ClientINFO(Application#,LDAReg#,Size,Name,SDW/O,CNIC,Address,Image,giventime) values (" + Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text) + ",'" + textBox2.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + " ','" + textBox5.Text + "','" + textBox6.Text+ "','" +textBox7.Text+ "','"+textBox8.Text +"','"+textBox3.Text+"')", con);
```

Comment: how can i check whether my connecti0on with database is established or not? please tellme

Comment: You have not connected to application database as ur error says, please check ur connection string

Answer (score 0):

There is problem in your SqlConnection

Make sure that your connection string is correct

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ali-pc/sqlexpress.PakEstateAgency.dbo");
```

It should come like

```
 SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN3-PC;Initial Catalog=master;Integrated Security=True");
```